# Android Studio, proxy, Gradle error: Connection refused: connect

Tags: android, networking

I am using Androd Studio under a proxy (dynamic proxy) then the internet connection works but the proxy cause a connection error on Gradle build.
The presented error:

> Connection refused: connect

It works if i am connected to a direct internet connection (no proxy).

There someone have solved this issue? There are settings to address it?
I have set the proxy on the Android Studio settings, it works on sdk manager.

UPDATE: A solution is to find the location of the file proxy.pac which contain the proxy's roles and identify a static proxy which could be used in Android Studio. For me it works.

Comment: I solved the problem by using a VPN connection, but if someone has any suggestion is welcome.